# Is it a good idea to pass the data context object to controllers with dependency injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I am currently using the CustomControllerFactory object to pass services (which each implement an interface) to my controllers.

I am wondering whether it is a good idea to do the same for my data context objects.

Currently at the top of each of my controllers, I have the line:

`private dataContextClass db = new dataContextClass();`

I have created an interface that dataContextClass implements. I can only see examples online of people passing services in with dependency injection. Is it a good idea to pass the data context object in as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's a good idea. The context is a dependency of your controller, and therefore should be injected if you're using dependency injection. However, you didn't specify what version of MVC you're using, but custom controller factories were deprecated in MVC 3. If you're using that version or later, you should be handling injection via `IDependencyResolver`. And, in general, it's usually better to just use a full-fledged DI container like Unity or Ninject, than to try to create your own from scratch.